# How to disable or bypass escape sequence in iOS string for Base64 Image url data

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimage, base64

I am receiving base64 strings from a json request from my server... 
The base64 strings look like this:
"/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD//gA7Q1J..." (well shortened)

Now my problem is that when I turn this from the NSString > NSURL, the backslashes escape from the string...
"/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD//gA7Q1J"

i.e. "/" turns into just "/"
Now I'm pretty sure that this is the problem for my encoding to a UIImage problems (going through the following method: NSString -> NSURL -> NSData -> UIImage)

Code to create UIImage:

```
    imageAllArray = [pathwayResults valueForKey:@"images_data_base64"];  
    NSURL *image2URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[imageAllArray objectAtIndex:1]];  
    NSData *image2Data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:image2URL];  
    imageTwo = [UIImage imageWithData:image2Data];
```

Does anyone know a way to ensure that the backslashes stay within the string to convert?

Or is there another/easier way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the backslashes weren't doing much harm at all and that it was because I forgot to prepend the string with: "data:image/png;base64,"

See below:

```
        NSString *prepender = @"data:image/png;base64,";
        NSString *image1String = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", prepender, [pathwayImageArray objectAtIndex:0]];
        NSURL *image1URL = [NSURL URLWithString:image1String];
        NSData *image1Data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:image1URL];
        imageOne = [UIImage imageWithData:image1Data];
```

Hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *encodedString = [@"your string" stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```